# Select statement to find variable data in a column

Tags: sql, sybase

Table name : - Trade

```
TradeNumber       spread
1                 .1
1                 .1
2                 .3
2                 .4
```

I want to get all the trades where spread varies. That is my result set should contain only trade number 2.

The query I could construct is

```
select TradeNumber from Trade t where t.spread <> (select t.spread from TradeNumber)
```

Didn't get a chance to run it. Is there an aggregating/ compound function to solve it ?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet       I am using sybase.

Comment: @Arpit   if you see, spread column has a value .2 and .3 for tradenumber 2, so it varies, whereas spread column has a value of .1,.1 for tradenumber 1, hence it does not vary.

Comment: I think DISTINCT(spread) is all that you are looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least expensive way to do this is:

```
select tradenumber
from t
group by tradenumber
having min(spread) <> max(spread)
```

Using `min` and `max` users fewer resources than `count(distinct)`.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus The result is correct. Thanks Gordon, though have no knowledge to comment on performance.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TradeNumber
FROM Trade t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM Trade t1
                  WHERE t.TradeNumber = t1.tradeNumber
                  AND t.spread <> t1.spread)
```

or

```
select TradeNumber
FROM Trade
GROUP BY TradeNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT spread) > 1
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9690/18)

Comment: Raphael Altaus: Hi, I will confirm the acceptance by tomorrow as I do not have access to the database right now. But can you help me understand the inner query ? What will be the resultset of inner query ?

Comment: Thanks for the link to sqlFiddle, Raphaël, I didn't know jsFiddle had a database quivalent :)

Comment: @gagansab well, second version is probably easier, without subQuery. For explanation : it checks if we can find another row with same TradeNumber but a different spread. EXISTS is a kind of a boolean check.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Thanks, I used the link to sql fiddle to verify the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, another solution.

```
SELECT TradeNumber FROM (
SELECT
TradeNumber
FROM
Trade
GROUP BY TradeNumber, spread
) sq
GROUP BY TradeNumber
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with

```
SELECT
TradeNumber
FROM
Trade
GROUP BY TradeNumber
HAVING count(distinct spread) > 1
```